# Magento 2: Disable search by SKU storefront

Tags: magento2, search, sku

I would like disable the storefront search by SKU.

I changed

[image]

but it still shows results by sku.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try Running the Reindex command in the command line.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```